# On the Proof of the Uniqueness/Existence Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality, proof-explanation

> I am trying to show that $$|\underline{x}(t)-\underline{y}(t)|\leq \left|\underline{x}(t_0)-\underline{y}(t_0)\right|+\int_{t_0}^{t}\left|\underline{f}(\underline{x},s)-\underline{f}(\underline{y},s)\right| \ ds,$$
>   where $$\underline{x}(t)=\underline{x}(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\underline{f}(\underline{x},s) \ ds, \ \underline{y}(t)=\underline{y}(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\underline{f}(\underline{y},s) \ ds.$$ This is part of my proof for the uniqueness/existence theorem.

This is my working so far.

\begin{align}
|\underline{x}(t)-\underline{y}(t)|&\leq |\underline{x}(t)|+\left|-\underline{y}(t)\right| \\
&= \left| \underline{x}(t_0)+\int_{t_0}^{t}\underline{f}(\underline{x},s) \ ds\right|+\left| -\underline{y}(t_0)-\int_{t_0}^{t}\underline{f}(\underline{y},s) \ ds\right| \\
&\leq |\underline{x}(t_0)|+\left|\int_{t_0}^{t}\underline{f}(\underline{x},s) \ ds\right|+\left|-\underline{y}(t_0)\right|+\left| -\int_{t_0}^{t}\underline{f}(\underline{y},s) \ ds\right| \\
\end{align}
I don't see how to combine the terms as desired.

Comment: First do the subtraction $x(t)-y(t)$, then take the absolute value (not the other way around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|(a+b)-(c+d)|=|(a-c)+(b-d)| \leq |a-c| +|b-d|$. (Your first step makes it impossible to complete the proof).  [Take $a$ and $b$ to be the first and second terms of $x(t)$ and $c$ and $d$ to be the first and second terms of $y(t)$].

Comment: Ah yes, thank you! For the final bit, is it true that $$\left|\int_{t_0}^t f(s)\right|\leq \int_{t_0}^{t}\left|f(s)\right| ds?$$

Comment: @sjmb Yes. $\ \ \ $